# How to access variables within another function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing code for a blackjack game and have run into some problems. I have written two functions: one for the initial deal and one for each consecutive hit. this is the deal function:

```
var deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"Jack","Queen","King","Ace"];

function deal() {
var card1_val = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
var card2_val = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
var card1 = deck[card1_val];
var card2 = deck[card2_val];

var hand = card1 + ", " + card2;

{//card1 Conditionals
if (card1 == "Jack") {
    card1_val = 10;
    }
else if (card1 == "Queen") {
    card1_val = 10;
    }
else if (card1 == "King") {
    card1_val = 10;
    }
else if (card1 == "Ace") {
    card1_val = 11;
    }
}

{//card2 Conditionals
if (card2 == "Jack") {
    card2_val = 10;
    }
else if (card2 == "Queen") {
    card2_val = 10;
    }
else if (card2 == "King") {
    card2_val = 10;
    }
else if (card2 == "Ace") {
    card2_val = 11;
    }
}

var res = card1_val + card2_val;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hand;
//document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = card1_val + ", " + card2_val;

if (res > 21) {
    alert("Blackjack!");
    }
}
```

This is the hit function:

```
function hit() {
var card_val = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
var nhand = deck[card_val];
bucket = hand + nhand
}
```

If you look at hit() I am using the var hand from deal(). I can't make it global because I need the value to be a fresh random each time. How do I access this same variable without rewriting lines of code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Return `hand` from `deal`: `return hand;`.

Comment: After returning hand how do I access the variable? I cannot call the function without refreshing the randoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either

- Declare `hand` outside of the function scope with just `var hand;` and use `hand` in the `deal` function without redeclaring it as a `var`;
- Or use `window.hand` when declaring `hand` in the `deal` function

Comment: They would both make it a global variable though.

Comment: If I make hand a global variable it will remain constant throughout the game (I'll have to refresh the page to start again). I don't want to have to do this (especially since I plan to incorporate a system to save scores). Is there any other way?

Comment: @user858962: You can just reset the variable when you start a new game.

Comment: @user why not just clear it when you want to clear it.  global variables aren't set in stone.

Comment: @user858962 can a player have more than one hand at the same time? If not, you can safely make it a global variable and just clear/modify/update it when necessary (new turn, player asks for new card, end of game, etc...). A global variable is not a constant, it's just a variable in the global scope (accessible everywhere)

Comment: maybe this is a noob question... but how does one reset a global variable?

Comment: @codeninja, I'm not sure what you mean by reset. But you can reassign it at will - `hand=null` in any section of your code will change the value of `hand` to `null` (if hand was declared in the global scope)

Comment: I was able to funnel local variables into the global scope using this method. The model I used was as follows:

function() {
window.GlobalVariableName = LocalVariableName
}

I could access the local variable in any number of other functions using the global varname I assigned within the function. thank you @Damp

Answer (score 0):

global variables are evil. i would take more object oriented approach, like this

```
var Hand = function(bjcallback) {

    this.cards = [];

    this.onblackjack = bjcallback;

    this.deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"Jack","Queen","King","Ace"];

    this.values = {
        "Jack": 10,
        "Queen": 10,
        "King": 10,
        "Ace": 11
    };

    this.sum = function() {
        var i, x, res = 0;
        for (i in this.cards) {
            x = this.cards[i];
            if (typeof(x) != 'number') { x = this.values[x] };
            res += x;
        };
        return res
    };

    this.pick = function() {
        var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.deck.length);
        var card = this.deck[pos];
        console.log(card);
        return card
    };

    this.deal = function(n) {
        n = n || 2;
        for (var i=0; i<n; i++) this.cards.push(this.pick())
    };

    this.hit = function() {
        this.cards.push(this.pick());
        if (this.sum() > 21) this.onblackjack();
    }
}

var hurray = function() { alert('Blackjack!') };
var hand = new Hand(hurray);

hand.deal();
hand.hit();
```

*note that i'm not much into cards so i might have confused terminology or counting*

Comment: @mykhal--i don't know much OOP... do you mind breaking down this approach? What's going on here?

Comment: @codeninja, it can be written simpler way, if you need only one `hand`, you can instead of `function Hand(){this.x = ...; this.y = ...}; hand = new Hand()` use `hand = {x: ..., y: ...}` and replace `this` with `hand`. to understanding js in more depth, i'd recommend this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Comment: @mykhal--your approach was helpful. I gave the check to the first answer because my knowledge of OOP is rudimentary at best. I had to go with the procedural approach. thank you though.